# Can a Bundle ID and SKU be reused in another iTunes Connect account?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I am in the process of deleting an app from iTunes Connect in order to upload it again in a new account for a new company.

From the iTunes Connect Developer Guide, I learn that the App Name can be reused as long as it is done from another account than the original one.
But how about the Bundle ID and the SKU? Can they also be reused? Or am I supposed to create new unique ones?

In my case, the new company will use the same URL as the old one, so when I ask about the Bundle ID, I refer to the full Bundle ID including the "com.company" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle id can't be reused as exact. For example com.abc.xxx can be used only once. If you had created this app Id from one account, you can't create the same app Id from the other account. However, you will still be able to create a new one as com.abc.xxx1 like or so. There should be atleast 1 character difference in the app Id's.

Also, App IDs cannot be removed because once allocated they need to stay alive, so that another App ID doesn't accidentally collide with a previously existing App ID.

Comment: So the fact that the "Bundle Seed ID" will differ is not sufficient? I actually need to change the Bundle ID?

Comment: Reading the iTunes Connect Developer Guide again, it says for Bundle Identifier: _"Your Bundle ID must be registered with Apple and **unique to your app**."_
 
Then it says for SKU: _"... is **unique to your developer account**"_

I guess this means that you are right, Nithin, in that Bundle IDs must be globally unique, but that an SKU can be identical to one in another account.

Answer (score -2):

If you can use same App name then you should able to use budle ID as well as SKU number as long as you are going to delete whole app. So I consider all of its metadata would be delete and can be reused.

Comment: Have you got any experience of this yourself?

Comment: Nope. It was just a thoughts.

Comment: OK. I share your thoughts, but I hope to get an answer from someone who has actually tried this. I am a bit cautious to try out unproven things in iTunes Connect. I do not want to cause myself troubles.