# iphone app id change bundle prefix

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program, app-id, bundle-identifier, app-bundle

We have 4 app ids on the Developer ios porthole.

```
prefix1.com.example.app1
prefix1.com.example.app2
prefix2.com.example.app3
prefix3.com.example.app4
```

These are all posted in the store.  The prefix2 and the prefix3 are older prefix numbers.  Prefix1 is our current number.  These apps have been in the store for a bit (years).

We require the prefix2 and prefix3 app to change to the prefix1 number for certain functions that we are doing.

We have tried to delete the prefix2 and prefix3 application IDs, but the error we get is "can not delete while application is in store." or something like that.

We have tried to add new IDs, with the new prefix, with the same bundle and we get the error "bundle already is used" or something like that.

How do we change the prefix on the app3 and app4 to the latest prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that as of this writing, you will need to contact Apple to have this done.  They will  respond with a confirmation and then start an "Engineering Ticket".  Not sure how long this is going to take.  Will post when it is done with how long it took.

Thanks to

[Is it safe to change the AppID Prefix between updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460586/is-it-safe-to-change-the-appid-prefix-between-updates)

and can contact apple at

-- Go to https://developer.apple.com/contact/.

-- Submit a request by clicking the link under Enrollment and Account.

Comment: Fyi, Apple was VERY responsive to this and took a day to two to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Developer Doc described the use of app id prefix, and also said that only  the team created before June 2011 could have more than one prefix.

So ,
1. you may not have choice to change prefix.
2. if your team have more than one prefix, but it also can't be changed. Only when create new app id, you can choose the prefix.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html