# Potential Loss of Keychain Access Issue After Application Move Account A To B in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keychain, sskeychain

Our iOS app is transfer from Account A to B, Earlier we had used the certificates which was created in Account A and upload a build on iTunes Connect using certificates of Account A.

Now when we uploading app on iTunesconenct for Beta Testing that time we have used the certificates which was created in Account B(Due to Transfer App Account).

So, Now application identifier of the live app is different from the application identifier of the Beta TestFlight Testing App on App Store. And we have got the warning potential loss of keychain access.

**Right Now, We are using SSKeychain Wrapper for Store UUID to track user.
[SSKeychain setPassword:UUID forService:@"com.example.appname” account:@“appname” error:&error]**

**If App ID Prefix changed then SSKeychain loss it’s access?**

**Because We track UUID in database for further use using SSKeychain. My doubt is if APPID Prefix changed then it is also effect the SSKeychain and it is generate new UUID for all devices?**

So, How we can solve this issue ? Please let us know about solutions of this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keychain access is tied to the App(s) ID Prefix(s).  They must have the same prefix.  We had a case where different Apps in the same Developer Account and different Prefix(s) and they would not share the same keychain access.  Had to have Apple fix so all were the same.

In your case, if you move the app to account B, the App ID will have a different prefix and would not be able to access the "old" keychain.

As far as I know there is NO workaround for this if the App Prefix has changed.

Yes, all devices would get a new keychain store for data and would not be able to access the "old" keychain data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. As per your comments( Had to have Apple fix so all were the same) is it possible to changed Account B AppID Prefix(Made same as Account A) using through apple service. If yes then how can request them? Thanks again and Waiting for your replay.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323522/iphone-app-id-change-bundle-prefix/27363598#27363598      Email them and they are pretty responsive for once.  Please report back if can change the ID.  I would assume no if both are active?