# Re-using the same bundle id after (permanently) app deletion from the iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a need to delete app completely, from the iTunesConnect (means, to remove it from sale, and then delete the app, all builds will be removed etc). But to be able later on, to re-create it, and re-upload it to the Store.

Would I be able to use same bundle ID as before? I ask this, cause I don't want to loose previous Firebase analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried this but in IAP identifier once its created then you can not reuse it again after deleting the IAP identifier (personally experienced it). It's permanently stored on the apple server. I think same is for the bundle ID too. You can not reuse it again.

Please read this post too : [Can a Bundle ID and SKU be reused in another iTunes Connect account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545837/can-a-bundle-id-and-sku-be-reused-in-another-itunes-connect-account) .

> Edit

**From apple forum [page](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81233)**

*You can't delete and/or reuse elsewhere. You can only transfer an app and it's associated bundle ID between paid accounts.*

**From [Apple doc](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev28d17ed35)**

*WARNING: If you remove an app, you will lose ownership of the app name. Removed apps can only be restored if the name is not currently in use by another developer account. In addition, the SKU can’t be reused in the same organization and if you’ve uploaded a build, your bundle ID can’t be reused.*

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really applies to my situation, cause my app doesn't have IAPs, nor I try to use different acc, lke from that link. I mean, you could be right about bundle id, but... I want to be sure.

Comment: @Whirlwind It is great risk and even I never required of it. I have experienced for IAP's and hoped same for bundle it. P.S. check the edit answer for sure.

Comment: I think I found it here : https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev28d17ed35

Comment: From the docs: WARNING: If you remove an app, you will lose ownership of the app name. Removed apps can only be restored if the name is not currently in use by another developer account. In addition, the SKU can’t be reused in the same organization and if you’ve uploaded a build, your bundle ID can’t be reused.

Comment: So this part :  *if you’ve uploaded a build, your bundle ID can’t be reused* ... Does it mean, if you never uploaded any build to the store, you can re-use same bundle Id, and otherwise no?

Comment: @Whirlwind  Once bundle Id is registered it stored on the apple server and you can't re-use it. I think it is the proper pattern. BTW it does not make any sense like you registered a bundleID and app is in dev phase. Now some other account create same bundle id and upload app. Now you can't upload the app,  even you registered ID first . I think it should be proper working like web domain but web domain you can re-use but not here.

Comment: That's why its recommended to create bundle-id as `com.organisation.app-name` so that it will be available most probably.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I getting confused about this part "....if you never uploaded any build to the **store**...." what did the mean by **store**? App Store Connect or just App Store?

Comment: @behrad He meant to upload the app on App Store. **App Store Connect** and **App Store** are same where you publish the apps.

Comment: I asked that question because I've uploaded an app to App Store Connect but didn't publish it in App Store (just using TestFlight) and I want to know after removing app from App Store Connect can I reuse same bundle ID.

Comment: @behrad, No, you can not reuse same bundle ID in the scenario you mentioned above. You need to change atleast one char in your bundle ID to upload the app.